# Under what conditions can an account be suspended? (EDIT: Case Closed)

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

This is a particular case, and I'm sorry if this is the wrong place for it; I didn't know where else to ask. Recently, a user had asked this question - "under what conditions do airplanes stall?" This was a good question, and recieved 5 answers including one from me. Unfortunately, this was a duplicate question, and rightfully so, it was taken down as one.

But about when this question was taken down, this user also had their account suspended - for a month. Now I find this objectionable because this user has asked several excellent questions in the past, with huge democratic support. They have also given some good answers to others' questions. They also have accounts across 40+ SE platforms.

Of course, I'm not sure if their account was suspended for asking a duplicate question or for some other reason, but the timing favours the former. Also, if you check their recent activity, there's absolutely nothing suspicious about it - it looks clean. So I think that their account might have been suspended due to some bug. Please review this situation.

UPDATE (by the questioner): This situation has been reviewed and has been fully understood; THIS CASE IS CLOSED. Thank you to the SE moderators for their support.

Comment: Of course their record looks clean. You should not be able to see anything for which a suspension is appropriate, because any inappropriate content should be deleted. Receiving a lot of votes on posts is also irrelevant, since upvotes do not determine whether a post is appropriate, just whether some individuals found it interesting.

Comment: @Nij I agree with you; the reason this question was posted by me is that I believed their suspension was a result of asking a duplicate question, since the time of suspension coincided with the time of closure of the question. Ralph J in their answer has confirmed that this was not the case - this was not the reason for the suspension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moderators don't generally discuss the situations of particular users publicly.

***Nobody*** gets suspended for asking a duplicate question, or even several.  No user has been suspended for *anything* related to this particular question, either.

There are times that mods see, and may act on, information that isn't available to all users. There are processes by which mods can be held to account for our actions, but a public inquiry isn't one of those.

For further info on suspensions in general:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165987/312025

[Avoiding getting suspended for voting irregularities?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199767/avoiding-getting-suspended-for-voting-irregularities)

[My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean)

[Why we don't keep public records of suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions)

[What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges)

Comment: Thank you, you have fully answered my question. Sorry for discussing this case here, I'm deleting this question right now. EDIT: I'm unable to delete it because "others have invested their precious time in it", you may remove it if you can...

Comment: No apology necessary; it's a totally fair question, and the timing does seem to suggest causality, even though in fact that is just happenstance. I'm inclined to leave the question & answer up, since it's a learning point for others. If you want to edit out the title of the original question in order to discourage future would-be detectives, that's fine with me.

Comment: Alright, this question will stay here. Thank you for your support, good day!